# Are any distros implementing a more secure CSPRNG in KASLR than RDRAND in lib/kaslr.c as in the vanilla sources?

Tags: kernel, random, cryptography

I started with [kaslr.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/boot/compressed/kaslr.c) and found that it uses kaslr_get_random_long() defined in [kaslr.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/include/asm/kaslr.h)  and implemented in [lib/kaslr.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/lib/kaslr.c) where it possibly uses RDRAND (Intel's hardware PRNG), a timestamp, and at least a  system timer to generate more entropy.

```
unsigned long raw, random = get_boot_seed();
bool use_i8254 = true;

debug_putstr(purpose);
debug_putstr(" KASLR using");

if (has_cpuflag(X86_FEATURE_RDRAND)) {
    debug_putstr(" RDRAND");
    if (rdrand_long(&raw)) {
        random ^= raw;
        use_i8254 = false;
    }
}

if (has_cpuflag(X86_FEATURE_TSC)) {
    debug_putstr(" RDTSC");
    raw = rdtsc();

    random ^= raw;
    use_i8254 = false;
}

if (use_i8254) {
    debug_putstr(" i8254");
    random ^= i8254();
}
```

The returned value is diffused a bit though some asm circular multiplication.

```
    /* Circular multiply for better bit diffusion */
asm(_ASM_MUL "%3"
    : "=a" (random), "=d" (raw)
    : "a" (random), "rm" (mix_const));
random += raw;
```

get_boot_seed seems to be a very simple linear xor PRNG on a hash set to a static 0. It uses a very simple xor relying on kernel boot parameters.

```
    /* Attempt to create a simple but unpredictable starting entropy. */
static unsigned long get_boot_seed(void)
{
    unsigned long hash = 0;

    hash = rotate_xor(hash, build_str, sizeof(build_str));
    hash = rotate_xor(hash, boot_params, sizeof(*boot_params));

    return hash;
}
```

This seems to be a "good enough" type of approach and was wondering if another distro has patched it to use a stronger CSPRNG? For a performance/security tradeoff, I can understand the choice. However, I'm fairly certain that someone must have already patched this to allow for more options for hardened kernels.

Comment: [Kernel ASLR is not very useful](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69054/does-kaslr-really-provide-more-security-against-exploits). I wouldn't bother.